# Training Restricted Boltzmann Machines according to the Likelihood Function

Tags: neural-networks, maximum-likelihood, deep-learning, approximation, restricted-boltzmann-machine

Is it possible to chose the parameters of a RBM to maximize the likelihood of the observed data?

(I follow the notation of the [deeplearning tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/rbm.html#rbm) ). Denote the observable data by $x$, hidden data by $h$, the energy function by $E$ and the normalizing constant by $Z$.  The probability of $x$ is: 
\begin{equation}
P(x) = \sum_h P(x,h) = \sum_h \frac{e^{-E(x,h)}}{Z}.
\end{equation}
In order to maximize the probability of $x$ conditional on the parameters of the model $\theta$ one could maximize the sum of the derivatives of the log-likelihood: 
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{x_i} \frac{\partial  \log p(x_i)}{\partial \theta}
 \end{equation} 
There exists many different ways to approximate the derivative of the log-likelihood to facilitate (permit) its computation. For example, Contrastive Divergence and Persistent Contrastive Divergence are used often. I wonder whether it makes sense to estimate the parameters $\theta$ recursively until convergence while continuing to approximate the derivative of the log-likelihood. One could update the parameters after seeing each data point $x_i$ as:
\begin{equation}
 \theta_{i+1} = \theta_{i} - \eta_i \frac{\partial  \log p(x_i)}{\partial \theta_i}
 \end{equation}
  The practice I learned in [Hinton et al. (2006)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1162/neco.2006.18.7.1527) and in Tieleman (2008) (I'm sorry: I cannot link to that paper due to insufficient reputation)  is different though: Both papers define a number of fixed iterations a priori. Could somebody kindly educate me why recursively updating the parameters until convergence is not a good idea? In particular, I'm interested whether there's a theoretical flaw in my reasoning or whether computational capacities dictate sticking to a fixed number of iterations. I am grateful for any help!